# Android geofencing: Reactnative vs Ionic vs NativeScript?

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic, native, nativescript

Задача:

Android-приложение для курьеров, которые по приходу на свой объект, будут помечать свое прибытие, далее идет трекинг их передвижения в фоне (геофенсинг) и как раз за время и пройденное расстояние они оплату и будут получать.

Какой фреймворк может справиться с этим?

Владею **VUE**.js (store, vuex), и как раз **Ionic** и **NativeScript** имеют интеграцию с вью.

Что посоветуете?

Побаиваюсь **ionicframework** потому, что там на сайте цены указаны, хотя и есть бесплатная версия, это не опенсорс, скорей всего это мышеловка.

Очень нуждаюсь в ваших отзывах...или хотя бы указании КУДА КОПАТЬ для добычи инфы.

Comment: 1) ionic+vue (cordova + webview);
2) nativescript+vue 
3) react-native

Comment: Framework7 + Vue.